# Как вставить ListView в макет

Tags: android

совсем недавно изучаю андроид, не судите строго.

В общем следующая задача: Делаю главное меню. По сути это ListView из макетов. Вот собственно макет.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

По умолчанию второй лист (который находится в макете) будет невидим и при нажатии на кнопку должен появляться. 
Как собственно реализуется этот второй список в список макета? Где именно инициализируется адаптер этого второго Листа? В в классе адаптера главного ЛистВью?

Comment: да, типа ыпадающее подменю

Comment: То есть у вас есть и горизонтальный listview и вертикальный. Элементы горизонтального - вертикальные listview. Я правильно понимаю?

Comment: если вам нужно выпадающее меню на айтемах списка, то это реализуется не через второй ListView, а через реализацию Context Menu или PopupMenu